# Fonts size issue in adding watermark on image laravel

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I'm using intervention Image in laravel for writing text over image. every things worked well except the fonts size. how can I make it bigger??
thanks for any help!

```
Image::make($avatar)
                ->text($store['watermark_text'], 120, 100, function($font) {
                    $font->size(75);
                    $font->color($_POST['colorr']);
                    $font->align('left');
                    $font->valign('bottom');
                    $font->angle(90);
                })->save(public_path('/store/products/'.$filename));
```

Comment: Seems like you need to define a font file to be able to change the size. [From the manual about size()](https://image.intervention.io/v2/api/text): _"Font sizing is only available if a font file is set and will be ignored otherwise. Default: 12"_

Comment: like this:   $font->family(myFont);  ???

Comment: The link I posted to their manual shows how to do it. `$font->file(string $filepath);` _"Set path to a True Type Font file"_. It even contains a proper example on how to use it.